His broad face beamed a hearty welcome

His broad face beamed a hearty welcome. (source)

I don't know how "broad" is being used in this sentence. There seem to be two possibilities to me:
(1) His face was being wide because of his smile.
(2) His face was wider than average.
Does the sentence imply (1) or (2)?
My native language (Japanese) does not have an expression like "face is wide with a smile", but I guess that (1) is more likely.
And I am unsure about "beamed a hearty welcome". Is "a hearty welcome" being likened to light?

The face does widen with a big smile as the cheek muscles contract and "his face broadened into a smile" is a cliche phrase, so it could be referring to his smile, but it could also be used of someone who did indeed have a broad face as distinct from a "long" one. No way to know with any certainty from a sentence in isolation.

Smiles are often called "bright" and faces in stories often are said to "beam".  I suppose it's the happy effect of the bared teeth. Maybe Desmond Morris has something to say about it :-)

I would definitely interpret this as (2). His face was generally wide and this face "beamed a hearty welcome". Broad is an adjective and so applies to the face not the beaming / smiling. To get the sense of your (1) you'd have to say something like "His face broadly beamed a hearty welcome" where broadly is an adverb applied to "beamed".

I wouldn't discount #1. People's faces can appear much wider (broader) because they have a larger than average smile.

@Mari-Lou "His broad face beamed" clearly implies that the face was broad and then beamed. I wouldn't consider any other meaning. If I was proof reading and thought meaning (1) was intended (from context) then I would have to rewrite it.

I can't find a literary source for this sentence, but Ngrams finds plenty of examples of broad face beamed. I'm pretty sure they all refer to a person with a wide face (associated with cheerfulness) who is smiling happily.
One sense of beam (verb) is 'to smile radiantly'. The person's smile demonstrates his warm welcome of the new arrival(s).

Ngram results: broad face beamed, faces beamed, her face beamed and his face beamed In reverse order of popularity. "broad face beamed" is used in literature, not so much  in everyday life.

This is the kind of question that comes up in English comprehension exams (or did, when I was at school). My interpretation is that the face was broad due to the smile - no.1 in your question.
I have seldom heard anyone's face described as broad, but smiles and grins are frequently "broad".

Really?  https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=broad+face&year_start=1800&year_end=2022&corpus=en&smoothing=3

@KateBunting  A number of those results appear to refer to a pub's name the "Broad Face" and quite a few are false positives. Besides Pete said they have seldom heard anyone's face being described as broad, which I tend to agree with.

That last link in particular, has 12 instances where "the broad face" is used. Always be aware that Ngram results can often be misleading. It is best to check the results below

@Mari-LouA - I'm aware that there can be false positives, but the ones I looked at definitely referred to people/images of people with wide faces.

Of course faces can be broad, wide, narrow, oval, round, smooth, square, chisel-shaped etc., but I would wager broad smiles outnumber broad faces.

Describing a face as broad may be unusual but I wouldn't consider it weird at all. It would be more usual to apply "broad" to a smile than a face, but that is clearly not what is being done in the original sentence. It is clearly the face that is broad.

"his broad face" is a better search term and there's no shortage of examples such as "a singular smile passed over his broad face" (1877), "...a smile upon his broad face." (2005) "his broad face shone with good-nature" (1858), etc. You might investigate what kind of mood/expression it's normally used with - narrow faces are often linked with sternness, parsimony, etc, and the fat jolly man is a stereotype.
